# Why is Mysql not using a part index?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table of IP addresses and RIR ranges and so want to link on the first 3 characters of the IP address in a join.

I have created the following index:
`CREATE INDEX My_range ON ranges (`Range`(3))`

I then run the following query:

`EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM ips
JOIN ranges rt ON SUBSTR(IPAddress,1,3) = SUBSTR(`Range`,1,3)
WHERE IPID = 17054`

And I don't see any indexes available on the rt line. What am I missing??

Comment: Indexes can only be used on raw column data and not on data that is processed by a function like `substr()`

Comment: Ahh! If you make that an answer I'll award that. Any solution to improving a query like the above then?

Comment: To add on what @juergend said, you may want to create another indexed column to hold the substring'd value and join on that instead.

Comment: Great idea thanks :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following quote is from @juergend in comments.

> Indexes can only be used on raw column data and not on data that is processed by a function like `substr()`.

To add on what he said, you may want to create another indexed column to hold the substring'd value and join on that instead.